# Capitalize First letter

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code to capitalize a first letter after a period "."

For example:

```
String str = "abcdef. ghijk, mlnopqrs. tuv .................." 
//the "............" means the line is still going on.
```

The output should be:

`"Abcdef. Ghijk, mlnopqrs. Tuv ................."`

Note: only use basic methods

String: `charAt`, `indexOf`, `length`, `substring`, `toUpperCase`

That means no `Stringbuilder`, no array, no split... etc. Other solutions I found in this site involve those things.

---

EDIT: thanks so much for the fast replies everyone. Just saw the edit of Robin Krahl. Yeah I forgot to add my code. 
My code look exactly like **mau**'s reply. But this code end up with this exception

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

And from here I don't know how to fix that -.-

Comment: Hints: To avoid `StringBuilder`, you can just concatenate strings with the `+=` operator.  To avoid arrays and the `split` method, use a loop. — We are not here to do your homework, so please show that you at least tried to solve the problem. Then we can assist you.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include code that perfectly solves your problem. Let me know if it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build a state machine with 2 states and have it scan the characters.

start in state 1: switch to state 2 if input is period

state 2: switch to state 1 if input is not period and not space

state 1: output the input without modification

state 2: if input is a character, output capitalized using `toUpper`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Capitalize {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    Capitalize instance = new Capitalize();
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      while (s.hasNext()) {
        instance.capitalize_and_print(s.nextLine());
      }
    }
  }

  public void capitalize_and_print (String s) {
    int state = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
      switch (state) {
        case 0:
          System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
          if (s.charAt(i) == '.') {
            state = 1;
          }
          break;
        case 1:
          System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
          if (s.charAt(i) != '.' && s.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            state = 0;
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:** Simpler version

```
public class Capitalize {
  public static void main (String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    int state = 2;
    int c = System.in.read();
    while (c != -1) {
      if (state == 1) {
        System.out.print((char)c);
        if (c == '.') {
          state = 2;
        }
      } else {
        System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase((char)c));
        if (c != '.' && c != ' ') {
          state = 1;
        }
      }
      c = System.in.read();
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 2:** even simpler version

```
public class Capitalize {
  public static void main (String [] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    String str = "abcdef. ghijk, mlnopqrs. tuv ..................";
    int state = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
      char c = str.charAt(i);
      if (state == 1) {
        System.out.print(c);
        if (c == '.') {
          state = 2;
        }
      } else {
        System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        if (c != '.' && c != ' ') {
          state = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can only use basic method :(

Comment: which method is not basic in my solution?

Comment: Capitalize instance = new Capitalize(); << this one, also "case", "switch", "try". I can only use "for", "while", "if" :(

Comment: ok, i will edit shortly

Comment: @LightAngels here you go, i have updated a simpler version.  again, tell me what is not basic in my solution and we will simplify further.

Comment: Thanks for being helpful. I'm only supposed to use System.out.print(ln) and out.print(ln) so what is System.in.read do? (char)c, throws java.io.IOException? I couldn't understand what your code do if I don't know that :( Sorry for being stupid

Comment: @LightAngels how about this?

Comment: A little confusing but I get it. It doesn't capitalize the first word but its good enough. Thank so much for your help.

Comment: @LightAngels ok, i have edited it so that it also capitalizes the first word.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with the logic part:

1. Find the substring till "."
2. Make the charAt the zeroth position of the substring to Uppercase.
3. Loop 1 to 2 until no more "." are present in the string
4. Concatenate the substrings

Hope this helps

Comment: "that means no Stringbuilder, no array, **no split** "

Comment: No splitting is allowed.

Comment: +1 when they close a question i upvote all answers, lol :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int length = str.length()
for(int x = 0; x < length-1; x++) {
  if(str.charAt(x) == '.') {
    str = str.substring(0,x+1) + (""+str.charAt(x+1)).toUpperCase() + str.substring(x+2,length+1);
  }
}
```

If the letter isn't directly after the period, either look two ahead, or loop to look for the next letter. You can say

```
letter = str.charAt(x);
if((letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z") || (letter >= 'a') && letter <= 'z'))
```

Comment: So very close, but you need to store the index at which the last char was found. As you walk along the array you update the last char if it isn't a space. If you find a stop you capitalise the char at the stored index.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this:

- Get the character array, with `String.toCharArray()`.
- Use a counter to look at each character in the array in turn.
- When you find a period, set a flag.
- When you find a letter while the flag is set, clear the flag and replace the character with its uppercase version.
- Once you've finished going through the loop, create a new String with `String.valueOf()`

Comment: "that means no Stringbuilder, **no array** , no split"

Comment: Didn't notice the array bit. Instead of an array, you could just append each character to a separate result string one at a time, but obviously that's inefficient.